# Value of closing jpa entitymanager vs. keeping it open

Tags: sqlite, jpa, entitymanager

I am running into an issue where if I try to close the entity manager, and then open open it again, my sqlite database is locking:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: database is locked
        at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:370)
        at org.sqlite.DB.exec(DB.java:76)
```

But if I just leave the entitymanager open, I don't see the error. So my question is, do I really need to close it? What if this is the only application that will be using this database, does that make a difference in whether or not it needs to be closed?

Here are the 2 methods I created. I was calling initTransaction(), then persisting my objects and committing, and then calling endTransaction(). The error would occur the second time I tried to do this, on tx.commit().

```
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private EntityManager em;
    private EntityTransaction tx; 

    //in my Java backing bean, multiple methods
        initTransaction();
        em.persist(someObject);
        tx.commit(); //Exception thrown here, but OK first time thru
        endTransaction();        

    private synchronized void initTransaction() {
      if (emf == null || !emf.isOpen()) { emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnitSqlite"); };   
      if (em == null || !em.isOpen()) { em = emf.createEntityManager(); }
      tx = em.getTransaction();
      if (!tx.isActive()) { tx.begin(); }
    }        

    private synchronized void endTransaction() {
      if (em != null) { em.clear(); em.close(); }
      if (emf != null) { emf.close(); }
      tx = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to close the EntityManager.  The EntityManagerFactory should not normally be closed, it should be held in a static variable as a singleton.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have done some more delving into it, and I understand now that the factory object should only be created once. From the JBoss docs: 'A EntityManagerFactory is an expensive-to-create, threadsafe object intended to be shared by all application threads. It is created once, usually on application startup.'

Comment: I also get that the EntityManager is a 'cache' of the data, but I still don't understand when exactly you should close it or keep it open.